# how to remove print button at hardcopy

Tags: javascript

i try to do this to hide my button on hardcopy  but still display at my hardcopy

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var button = document.getElementById('print') button.addEventListener('click',hideshow,false);
function printFrom_hidden()
{

    document.getElementById('print').style.display="block";
    //document.getElementById('').style.display = ;
    this.style="display:none";
}
</script>

<input type="button" value="Print" name="print" id="print" onClick="printFrom();printFrom_hidden();">
```

Comment: So you want to click your `print` button and have in disappear?

Comment: You should include the code of the `hideshow()` function as well. Also, this could be achieved with only [a print stylesheet](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/) and no JS.

Answer (score 4):

May I suggest using media types for CSS stylesheets for this purpose?  See http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Writing a stylesheet for the printer is far superior to hacking out changes to the screen's styles to make it printer-suitable.  For your purposes, it should be as simple as something like adding this to your stylesheet

```
@media print {
    input#print { display: none }
}
```

To my understanding this is the way it's meant to be done.  Sadly, Web developers and designers all to often forget that not everything is a screen!

Answer (score 1):

You are calling printForm(); first and then printFrom_hidden(). So your print button is hidden after your print is done. So inverse them.

```
<input type="button" value="Print" name="print" id="print" onClick="printFrom_hidden();printFrom();">
```

Answer (score 0):

yourpage.php or yourpage.html or yourpage.aspx or whatever

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <style type='text/css'>
      @import 'common.css'; @import `yourpage.css';
    </style>
  </head>
<body class='njs'>
  <input type='button' value='Print' name='print' id='print' />
  <script type='text/javascript src='common.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript src='yourpage.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

common.js

```
//<![CDATA[
var doc = document, bod = doc.body, IE = parseFloat(navigator.appVersion.split('MSIE')[1]);
bod.className = 'js';
function gteIE(version, className){
  if(IE >= version)bod.className = className;
}
function E(e){
  return doc.getElementById(e);
}
//]]>
```

yourpage.js

```
//<![CDATA[
E('print').onclick = function(){
  print();
}
//]]>
```

Of course, use CSS like `Dan Farrell` suggested.

yourpage.css

```
#print{
  /* print button CSS when not in print mode */
}
@media print{
  /* CSS for this page goes in here */
  body{
    /* body CSS here */
  }
  #print{
    /* print button CSS here */
  }
}
```